# aws - Uploading a string as file to a S3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to save a string as a file to an AWS S3 bucket using the AWS SDK for NodeJS. The PUT request gets succeeded, but the file does not get created in the S3 bucket. Following is a snippet from my code.

```
const s3 = new S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });

const JS_code = `
  let x = 'Hello World';
`;

// I'm using the following method inside an async function.
await s3.putObject({
        Bucket: 'my-bucket-gayashan',
        Key: 'myFile.js',
        ContentType:'binary',
        Body: Buffer.from(JS_code, 'binary')
      });
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use [promise()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html#promise-property) with `await`:

```
await s3.putObject({...}).promise();
```

Comment: oh man.. take me an hour until i get here... such a mistake... Thank you!

Comment: putObject does not return a promise(), you just need to use await as long as your handler is async

Answer (score 1):

You should provide a valid MIME type in the `ContentType` field. In your case it should be `application/javascript`.

Comment: Still, I'm getting the same result as before.

Comment: Hmm, can you try to set `Body: JS_code` to upload it just as a string?

Comment: Strange, I just tried and it worked for me. Maybe something with credentials, are you sure that the request completes ok?

Can you try it like this?

```s3.putObject({
        Bucket: 'my-bucket-gayashan',
        Key: 'myFile.js',
        ContentType:'binary',
        Body: Buffer.from(JS_code, 'binary')
      }, (error, response) => console.log(error, response));```

Comment: `putObject` doesn't return a promise, so I don't understand why you use it with await.
You should pass a callback to `putObject` and most likely you will see some error.

Comment: OK, I think the problem was that I wasn't chaining the promise() method at the end of putObject() method as per Khalid T's answer below. It solved the issue.