# Write CSV into Amazon S3 bucket without storing it on local machine

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I wanted to upload CSV data(not a CSV file) to Amazon S3 Buckets using Node.js. Some of the answers I could find included uploading a CSV file to Amazon S3 Bucket. But what my use case is to format my data that I get back from some API that I am using, into a CSV format and then uploaded a CSV file corresponding to this data to S3 Buckets. How can I achieve this?

```
const s3 = new S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });

const csv_text = `
  'First','Second','Third' 
`;

await s3.putObject({
        Bucket: 'my-bucket-name',
        Key: 'myFile.js',
        ContentType:'application/octet-stream',
        Body: Buffer.from(csv_text, 'application/octet-stream')
      });
```

Comment: You want to use [putObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49917935/aws-uploading-a-string-as-file-to-a-s3-bucket)

Comment: How big is the file?

Comment: @Marcin 200-300kb

Comment: @AnonCoward I have updated the question with the code for a csv file, but I don't get what to use as ContentType and what to pass as 2nd parameter to Buffer.from() method. I read applicaton/octet-stream works for csv files. Is this correct now ?

Comment: The .csv MIME type is `text/csv`.  The Key is up to you, whatever you want to name the object in S3.